# How to view feeds from multiple sources in RSS android application

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to android development so all help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to view feeds from multiple sources in an rss application i'm developing. currently i only have one single "feed" hardcoded into the source code.

I figure i could approach it by storing a list of all the sources i want in a text file in the assets folder and having the application use that list to fetch the feeds. I am basically having issues with figuring out how to implement the coding, since i'm not very good with android coding. The main reason is cause for now i need to be a be to prove that the application can communicate with a source to get and retrieve data and also because future developments would require the user be able to manually add sources so i figure they can be written to and retrieved from the text file

if theres a much more easier or straightforward way to go about this i would be welcome to any suggestion.

Thanks

**EDIT** Made some changes to my code below, still doesn't run but using the debugger i can tell that it actually reads the file, the problem seems to be at `String[] RssLinksArray = readLine.split("[\\;]+");` where the code terminates, i can't for the life of me figure out why. i'm attaching the logcat also.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
package com.simplerssreader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class RssService extends IntentService 
{
public static final String ITEMS = "items";
public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

public RssService() 
{
    super("RssService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{   
            String rsslink = "";
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           rsslink +=line ;
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String RSS_LINK = rsslink;

    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
    List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
    try 
    {
        XMLRssParser parser = new XMLRssParser();
        rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
    } 
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
    {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
    receiver.send(0, bundle);
}

public InputStream getInputStream(String link) 
{
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Exception while retrieving the input stream", e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
10-24 23:07:49.908: D/dalvikvm(1189): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 101K, 9% free 2778K/3040K, paused 68ms, total 72ms
10-24 23:07:49.938: I/dalvikvm-heap(1189): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.939MB for 1127536-byte allocation
10-24 23:07:50.089: D/dalvikvm(1189): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3877K/4144K, paused 149ms, total 149ms
10-24 23:07:50.461: W/dalvikvm(1189): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RssService]
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at com.simplerssreader.RssService.onHandleIntent(RssService.java:48)
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 23:07:50.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-24 23:07:50.899: D/libEGL(1189): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-24 23:07:50.940: D/(1189): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1db628, tid 1189
10-24 23:07:51.078: D/libEGL(1189): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-24 23:07:51.279: D/libEGL(1189): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
10-24 23:07:51.699: W/EGL_emulation(1189): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-24 23:07:51.729: D/OpenGLRenderer(1189): Enabling debug mode 0
10-24 23:07:51.769: I/Choreographer(1189): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 23:07:56.358: I/Choreographer(1189): Skipped 265 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a `XML parser` in Android then you can go through my following post on the blog. It uses the XML source from sdcard. You can simply set the source to web based RSS.
http://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/xml-parsing-android-java/

What you want is to put the `RSS` sources in a text file, so you will require to look at reading text file in android.

**Edit**

Reading the text file from `res` folder inside a raw folder

```
InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String readLine = null;

        try {
            while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Sample text for `RSS links` in the text file

```
http://yourlink/rss1.xml;http://yourlink/rss2.xml;http://yourlink/rss3.xml
```

Now after you read the file the text above is in `readLine` String variable. Now apply the split function of a String class on `readLine` variable.

```
String[] RssLinksArray = readLine.split(';');
```

Pointing to the links in the array like this

```
RSS-Link = RssLinksArray[0];
```

Comment: yes what i want to do is put the sources in a text file and have it read them from there as if it was reading the hard coded source. i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707256/read-text-file-as-resource while i was searching with regards to reading from a file, not sure if its any good, was hoping you could give me some pointers

Comment: See my edit, you should try the above according to your requirements.

Comment: Alright, one more question if you don't mind. even if i add the lines of code to the RssService class, how do i about making RSS-LINK point to the contents of the file

Comment: What you need to do for that is, place the url in the text file, add an identifier like ";" semicolon in between every link and then split the text you read in the readline. This will give you an array of the urls which you can point to the RSS-LINK as required.

Comment: Tried what you proposed *see edit above* but it wouldn't even run, it tried to start and the application force closes

Comment: Hi @jibran, i made some changes but it still isn't working..could u please help

Comment: What problem you are facing ? you might need to share the issue occurring

Comment: The buffered reader never sends the link in the file to the Array, i even tried using just one link but even that doesnt work, it returns null all the time

Comment: have you tried to debug the code that if it is actually getting text from the file ?

Comment: ohh yes it is actually getting the text from the file, i opened another thread to deal with the issue of just one link without an array and it got solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582100/bufferedreader-returning-null/19582134?noredirect=1#19582134

Comment: to an extent yes it is, thanks alot..but might i bother u on how to have it deal with more than one link. right now all it can deal with is just one link in the file, i updated the code with the right solution for just one

Comment: @DavidF Hey, any luck with this? I'm also trying to do the same thing. I only have one RSS feed hardcoded into the source. I want to display multiple RSS feeds on one activity. Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

here is the below tutorial for rss feed from url..

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-rss-feed-reader-example.html

and also you can see async task to getting feed and also custom listview with images.

Comment: What this person has is sort of similar to what i already have in place. he hard coded the url for the feed into the source code. i am trying to avoid doing that by using the method described above