# Bufferedreader returning null

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, readline

i'm trying to read a web address from a text and then have the app open that address, my buffered reader seems to be reading the lines correctly but readline keeps coming back null

```
String rsslink = null;
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((rsslink = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {

        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String RSS_LINK = rsslink;

    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
    List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
    try 
    {
        XMLRssParser parser = new XMLRssParser();
        rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
```

Comment: Have tried your code working my side, have you put the xml in raw folder.

Comment: The solution is any of the methods they suggested below. it wasn't an xml file, it was a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the last line that is `null rsslink`. 
You need to change your loop

```
try {
        while ((rsslink = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {

        }
    }
```

to

```
 try {
        StringBuilder sb=  new StringBuilder();
        while ((rsslink = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
               sb.append(rsslink);
        }
        rsslink = sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: @user2310289  yes you are correct. thanks updated your suggestion.

Comment: it does exactly that, it makes rsslink the link twice, and then when it steps out it returns rsslink to null

Comment: Thank you very much, now i need to figure out how to have it deal with more than one link within the file using a delimiter..thanks again

Comment: i'm trying to add a delimiter so it can pick up more than one link i tried adding `read.useDelimiter(";")` to the bufferedreader but that doesn't work. Any pointers??

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String rsslink = "";
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
       rsslink +=line ;
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String RSS_LINK = rsslink;

Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
try 
{
    XMLRssParser parser = new XMLRssParser();
    rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
```

Better your [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder rsslink = new StringBuilder();
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
       rsslink.append(line);
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String RSS_LINK = rsslink.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it also worked. unfortunately i can only choose one solution..but thanks alot